# Euler's method for Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, differential-equations

I want to approximate the solutions of dy/dx = -x +1, with eulers method on the interval from 0 to 2. I'm using this code

```
def f(x):
    return -x+1  # insert any function here


x0 = 1  # Initial slope #
dt = 0.1  # time step
T = 2  # ...from...to T
t = np.linspace(0, T, int(T/dt) + 1)  # divide the interval from 0 to 2 by dt
x = np.zeros(len(t))
x[0] = x0 # value at 1 is the initial slope
for i in range(1, len(t)):  # apply euler method
    x[i] = x[i-1] + f(x[i-1])*dt

plt.figure()  # plot the result
plt.plot(t,x,color='blue')
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.ylabel('y(t)')


plt.show()
```

Can I use this code to approximate the solutions of any function on any interval? It's hard to see whether this actually works, because I don't know how to plot the actual solution ( -1/2x^2 + x ) along side the approximation.

Comment: I am a bit confused but have You tried using `print()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just plot the actual solution by using:

```
def F(x):
   return -0.5*x+x

# some code lines

plt.plot(t,x,color='blue')
plt.plot(t,F(t),color='orange')
```

But please note that the *actual* solution (-1/2x+x = 1/2x) does not correspond to your slope *f(x)* and will show a different solution.

The **real slope f(x)* of the *actual* solution (-1/2x+x = 1/2x) is just simply `f(x)=1/2`

Comment: Sorry, the actual solution I wrote was wrong. It is -1/2 x^2 +x

Comment: Then you should use `def F(x):  return -1/2*x* *2 +x`.
Also note, that the explicit euler will yield a pretty bad approximation for the **Initial Point** (not initial slope!) **x0=1**

Answer (score 2):

It would probably help if you consistently used the same variable names for the same role. Per your output, the solution is `y(t)`. Thus your differential equation should be `dy(t)/dt = f(t,y(t))`. This would then give an implementation for the slope function and its exact solution

```
def f(t,y): return 1-t

def exact_y(t,t0,y0): return y0+0.5*(1-t0)**2-0.5*(1-t)**2
```

Then implement the Euler loop also as a separate function, keeping out problem specific details as much as possible

```
def Eulerint(f,t0,y0,te,dt):
    t = np.arange(t0,te+dt,dt)
    y = np.zeros(len(t))
    y[0] = y0 
    for i in range(1, len(t)):  # apply euler method
        y[i] = y[i-1] + f(t[i-1],y[i-1])*dt
    return t,y
```

Then plot the solutions as

```
y0,T,dt = 1,2,0.1
t,y = Eulerint(f,0,y0,T,dt)
plt.plot(t,y,color='blue')
plt.plot(t,exact_y(t,0,y0),color='orange')
```

[image]